# Count function calls in python using decorator

Tags: python, fibonacci, memoization, python-decorators

I came across the following piece of python in one of the class note. I understand the concept of high order function and the memoization technique used here. But I am confused about what counted_fib and fib actually refer to here after the last several assignments. Could anyone give me some explanations?

```
def count(f):
    def counted(n):
        counted.call_count += 1
        return f(n)
    counted.call_count = 0
    return counted

def memo(f):
    cache = {}
    def memoized(n):
        if n not in cache:
            cache[n] = f(n)
        return cache[n]
    return memoized

def fib(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 0:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

fib = count(fib)
counted_fib = fib
fib = memo(fib)
fib = count(fib)

print(fib(30))
print(fib.call_count)
print(counted_fib.call_count)
```

which gives the results:

```
832040
59
31
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to count how many times a function was called you could do just that:

```
def fib(n):
    fib.count += 1  # increase counter
    if n == 1 or n == 0:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
fib.count = 0       # initialize counter

print(fib(5))    #  5
print(fib.count) # 15
```

your `def count(f)` is just a decorator around the function `f` that adds the additional statements necessary for the counter (the initializing and increasing of the counter) and returns the decorated function.

```
def counted(n):
    counted.call_count += 1
    return f(n)
```

creates a new function that has an additional variable `counted.call_count` which is increased every time the function is called. `return f(n)` then calls the function and returns the return value.

```
counted.call_count = 0
return counted
```

this then initializes the counter and returns the decorated function.

now for the last 3 lines:

```
fib = count(fib)
fib_counted = fib             # save the counted function of the bare fib
fib_memo = memo(fib)          # meomize fib
fib = count(fib_memo)         # add a counter to the meomized version
print(fib(30))
print(fib.call_count)         # 59: the meomized version was called 
                              #     ~2 times per distinct argument
print(fib_counted.call_count) # 31: i.e.: the memo called the original fib
                              #     once per distinct argument.
```

what makes all that a bit hard to read is the fact that the `fib` function calls itself (recursion). therefore the functions can not be called a new name (except for the meomized version). that would make things easier...

Comment: I understand what you are saying but that is not what I am asking.

Comment: @ChenChen: you are correct. tried to add a little comment on that. hope that helps.

Comment: I somehow got your point but still a lit bit confused. Instead of all the assignments in the original code, consider the following ones fib = count(memo(fib)); fib_counted = count(fib) and do prints as before. Then fib_counted.call_count is giving 0. Why is that?

Comment: because now you never call `fib_counted`; you'd still need to call `fib_counted(30)` in order to get a non-zero call-count.